# Package SendGrid 9.25.2 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). SendGrid 9.25.2 does not support any target frameworks

Tags: .net-6.0, sendgrid

Unable to install Sendgrid 9.25.2, under .Netcore version net6.0

net6.0

```
error: NU1202: Package SendGrid 9.25.2 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package SendGrid 9.25.2 does not support any target frameworks.
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SendGrid/9.25.2

Comment: Are installing this package in a solution with multiple projects?

Comment: @DenisMicheal  Yes, I have other projects in sln.

Comment: Share your `.csproj` of the project where you are adding this package.